# Why is my correlation matrix dropping that many NA?

Tags: correlation, text-mining, topic-models, networks

I am trying to build a correlation matrix among documents per topic on a Latent Dirichlet Allocation model by text2vec, getting a doc_topic_distr matrix like below, with only first 5 documents, it's a total of 23456.

```
    V1          V2          V3          V4          V5          V6          V7          V8          V9          V10
1   0.00000000  0.100000000 0.0000000   0.00000000  0.40000000  0.0000000   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.50000000  0.00000000
2   0.00000000  0.000000000 0.0000000   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.0000000   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
3   0.00000000  0.000000000 0.0000000   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.0000000   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
4   0.00000000  0.000000000 0.0000000   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.0000000   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
5   0.02500000  0.000000000 0.0250000   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.0250000   0.40000000  0.00000000  0.52500000  0.00000000
```

I am using this code to get igraph library extracting edges and nodes

```
dtd <- t(doc_topic_distr)
dtd_num_col <- ncol(dtd)
cor_threshold <- .8
dtd_cor <- cor(dtd[,1:dtd_num_col], method = "pearson")
    1   2   3   4   5
1   1   NA  NA  NA  0
2   NA  1   NA  NA  NA  
3   NA  NA  1   NA  NA  
4   NA  NA  NA  1   NA  
5   0   NA  NA  NA  1

dtd_cor[ dtd_cor < cor_threshold ] <- 0
diag(dtd_cor) <- 0
graph <- graph.adjacency(dtd_cor, weighted=TRUE, mode="lower")
```

But I am getting many NAs as outcome on the correlation matrix as shown below and I just can't figure out why, could somebody please let me know and, if fixable, how to?

````
    1   2   3   4   5
1   0   NA  NA  NA  0.0000000   
2   NA  0   NA  NA  NA  
3   NA  NA  0   NA  NA  
4   NA  NA  NA  0   NA  
5   0   NA  NA  NA  0.0000000
```
````

Comment: Is it R you are using? From the Corr Matrix, i know you did something wrong when you calculated the matrix, because for diagonal, it should be all 1s but you have all 0s.

Comment: @JohnLi if you could take a look at the coding, I did it on purpose with this `diag(dtd_cor) <- 0`. Yes indeed, this is R programming

Comment: Just read through your code, notice you have set cor threshold to 0.8 and set diagonal to 0. maybe its worthy of taking a look at your dtd_cor before you apply the two operations?

Comment: @JohnLi I actually did, it is giving that 1 diagonal you mention and numbers as supossed to, where there ain't NAs

Comment: I am not very familiar with R, but maybe the NA is because some of your rows have all zeros? From your sample, doc 2, 3, 4 are all zero rows. not sure if the 10 columns are you have.

Comment: @JohnLi Excuse the basic question, but then if it is a sparse row, ends up producing NA?

Comment: It shouldn't. From what you described, you did get real numbers before you applied the threshold and diagonal operations to your dtd_cor matrix which leads me to think maybe the NA is caused maybe when you subtract between different data types?

Comment: Most of the columns you show have no variance, making it impossible to compute their covariance with anything.  This would be clearer if you didn't impose zero values on the diagonal elements, which effectively papers over the problem without solving it.

Comment: Your example is very clear: rows 2 through 4 of the data are all zeros.  Because there's no variation, there cannot be any co-variation, whence the covariances and the correlations are undefined.  Aren't you getting a warning message stating something like "`In cor( ... ) : the standard deviation is zero`"?